# Cypher return a node with the given neighbors

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to write a query in Cypher which is able to find a single node with the label :CONVERSATION having the given neighbor nodes. The neighbor nodes are users with the label :USER and a property called "username". 
In the query a list of "username"s is given and a desired is to find a conversation node which has as its neighbor all the users with the username in the given list. 
I have tried some queries but they don't return what I want. Is there anyone who has any idea how the query may look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are passing the given usernames as a `{users}` parameters and the relationship between your users and the conversations is named `IN_CONVERSATION` :

```
MATCH (c:Conversation)
WHERE ALL( x IN {users} WHERE (:User {name:x} )-[:IN_CONVERSATION]->(c) )
RETURN c
```

If you want to test the query by passing the usernames in the neo4j browser for eg, you can simulate the parameters with `WITH` :

```
WITH ["adam","john","sally"] AS users
MATCH (c:Conversation)
WHERE ALL( x IN users WHERE (:User {name:x} )-[:IN_CONVERSATION]->(c) )
RETURN c
```

Another solution is to match first the users also :

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.name IN {users}
MATCH (c:Conversation)
WHERE ALL( x IN collect(u) WHERE (x)-[:IN_CONVERSATION]->(c) )
RETURN c
```